# Prevent react app from setting state again when pressed back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am building a Simple React App and I am using api to set state and I am using `Link` to get into detail page But When I go into another page from `Link` and press back button then It is setting state again. But I am trying to prevent setting state again when I go back to the page from back button.

App.js

```
function MainPage() {
    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useStae([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("/api/blogs/").then((res) => {
            setBlogs(res.data.blogs);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            {
               blogs.map((res) => <>

                   <b>{res.title}
                   // It is showing about 40 blogs.

                   <Link to={`blog-detail/${res.id}`}>Blog Detail</Link>4
                </>
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

When I click on `Blog Detail` and press button in `Browser` (Chrome) then It is setting state again.

**What I have tried ?**

1. I have also thought about `Using LocalStorage with Redux Store` like :-

```
const saveToLocalStorage = (state) => {
  try {
    localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

But the Array was `40` in length then I thought `Would it be efficient to store that big array (40 maybe 100(max))` in localStorage ?`

Then I cancelled it.

2. Using only localStorage without `redux` but It was localStorage after all.

I have tried many times but it is still setting state with makeing request to backend server.

Any help would be much Appreicated.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to save the api call so it doesn't refetch if you return to the page. Usually we move this api fetch logic outside of the component and pass the data in via props or the context api.

Comment: Yes, I want to store it but I only need it when going back or forward.

Comment: Check out [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html#how-to-use-context). It will do what your asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the `MainPage` component from running the effect each time it mounts then you'll need to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common parent/ancestor component that remains mounted while the app's router is matching and rendering different routed content/pages/components.

You can move the `blogs` state up to the component rendering the routes so the data is fetched only once when mounted and lives for the duration of the component's life. ***Don't forget to include a dependency array for the `useEffect` hook!***

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/blogs/")
      .then((res) => {
        setBlogs(res.data.blogs);
      });
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency array, run effect once on mount

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/blog"
        element={<MainPage blogs={blogs} />} // <-- pass blogs as prop
      />
      <Route
        path="/blog-detail/:id"
        element={<BlogDetails blogs={blogs} />} // <-- pass blogs as prop
      />
    </Routes>

  );
};
```

...

```
function MainPage({ blogs }) { // <-- consume blogs as prop
  return (
    <>
      {blogs.map((blog) => (
        <React.Fragment key={blog.id}>
          <b>{blog.title}</b>
          // It is showing about 40 blogs.

          <Link to={`blog-detail/${blog.id}`}>Blog Detail</Link>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Switching/navigating between routes now will no longer trigger the `useEffect` hook to refetch the blogs data.